Isometries in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$
I don´t know if my solution to this problem is complete and 100% correct. I´d appreciate some feedback.
Let $f$ and $h$ be two isometries in $(\mathbb{R}^{3}, \langle, \rangle)$. If $f$ is the symmetry with respect to a plane $\Pi$, prove that $h\circ f \circ h^{-1}$ is the symmetry with respect to the plane $h(\Pi)$.
My attempt:
Let $B = (u_{1}, u_{2}, u_{3})$ be an orthonormal basis such that $\Pi = \mathrm{span} (u_{1}, u_{2})$. Then the matrix of $f$ with respect to $B$ is
$$
M(f,B) = \pmatrix{
         1 & 0 & 0\\
         0 & 1 & 0\\
         0 & 0 & -1
         }
$$
So
$$
\operatorname{det} (f) = -1\ \  \text{and}\ \ \operatorname{tr}(f) = 1
$$
Note that
$$
\operatorname{det} ( h\circ f \circ h^{-1}) = \det (f) = -1
$$
and
$$
\operatorname{tr} (h \circ f \circ h^{-1}) = \operatorname{tr} (f) = 1.
$$
This means that $h \circ f \circ h^{-1}$ is the symmetry with respect to a plane. Now let $v \in h(\Pi)$ so that $v = h(au_{1}+bu_{2})$ for some $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. Then
$$
(h\circ f \circ h^{-1}) (v) = (h\circ f \circ h^{-1}) (h(au_{1}+bu_{2})\\
                            =h(f(au_{1}+bu_{2}))\\
                            = h(af(u_{1}) + bf(u_{2}))\\
                            = h(au_{1}+bu_{2})\\
                            = h(v),
$$
where the fourth equality comes from the fact that $f$ fixes $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$. This means that $h(\Pi)$ is fixed by $h \circ f \circ h^{-1}$. So, since $h \circ f \circ h^{-1}$ is a symmetry with respect to a plane, it cannot fix the three basis vectors and the eigenspace associated to $-1$ has dimension 1. Therefore it is the symmetry with respect to $h(\Pi)$.

Ok provided you are able to prove that an isometry with det=-1 and tr=1 is a symmetry w.r.t. a plane. Alternatively,  check directly (without $B$ and $M(f,B)$) that the isometry $h\circ f \circ h^{-1}$ maps every vector of the plane $h(\Pi)$ to itself and every vector of the line $h(\Pi^\bot)$ to its opposite.
